# Salesforce: Check if ApexTrigger is active in test Method

Tags: triggers, tdd, salesforce, apex-code

I have a test method that makes assertions based on a trigger that will run before the record is inserted.

In some cases the the trigger will be made inactive, which results in the test case failing.

How can I check the Status of the trigger in the test case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In hindsight this wasn't that difficult. Just do a quick query at the start of the test method and return if the Status for the trigger is Inactive.

```
ApexTrigger defaultPriceBookTrigger = 
    [Select Id, Status from ApexTrigger where name='DefaultPriceBook'];
if(defaultPriceBookTrigger.Status == 'Inactive'){
    return;
}
```